# windows authenticated website prompt for firefox but doesn't for internet explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, windows-authentication

i added windows authentication on my website to track user names.  For IE it works fine and is seemsless but it prompts for windows login for user using firefox.  any ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You'll need to enable NTLM authentication in Firefox. [Instructions here.](http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/)

1. Open Firefox and type “about:config” in the address bar. (without the quotes of course)
2. In the ‘Filter’ field type the following “network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris”
3. Double click the name of the preference that we just searched for
4. Enter the URLs of the sites you wish to pass NTLM auth info to in the form of:
   `http://intranet.company.com,http://email.company.lan`
5. Notice that you can use a comma separated list in this field.

Answer (score 7):

- Open Firefox
- In the Address bar type **about:config**
- In the search/filter field type **ntlm**
- Set **network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris** to `.company_name.com`
- Set **network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-non-fqdn** to `true` by
  right-clicking and selecting "toggle"
- In the search/filter field type **negotiate**
- Set **network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris** to `.company_name.com`
- Set **network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn** to `true` by right-clicking
  and selecting "toggle"
- Click OK if present
- Restart Firefox.

From http://perfect-blog-url.blogspot.com/2013/07/firefox-asks-for-user-name-and-password.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the hostname (URL) to the **network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris** setting within **about:config** in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

**Internet Explorer configuration:**

1. Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced tab and check the “Enable Integrated Windows Authentication” check-box.
2. Next, switch to the security tab and click Local Intranet -> Custom Level and select “Automatic log-on with current user name and password” (under User Authentication, Log-on).
3. Click OK on all windows and restart Internet Explorer (close all IE windows and open it again).

**Firefox configuration:**

about:config and "network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris" and ".example.com"

Answer (score 0):

Windows authentication does not work for Firefox out of the box.  You will need to do some [additional steps](http://codebetter.com/blogs/eric.wise/archive/2006/11/16/Note-to-self_3A00_-Firefox-Windows-Authentication.aspx).  I'm not sure of the particulars as to how it happens, but your domain credentials are somehow given to the web server using IE.